# Selector not getting active despite being readable

Tags: java, multithreading, selector, nio

I'm currently working on a faculty projecty using UDP Multicast.
I'm trying to implement NIO since I have to deal with 3 channels.
Basically one of the objectives is to split a file into chunks, and then send those chunks to a multicast group in order to be stored.

My problem is, I actually send all chunks, but don't receive them all.. From chunk 1 to chunk 4 usually it goes good, but then it skips chunks, and by skipping i mean that the channel doesn't get readable.

Here's the code that deals with the selector and the channels:

```
//Peer Class Constructor
public Peer(String mcast_addr, int mcast_port, String mcastbackup_addr, int mcastbackup_port, String mcastrestore_addr, int mcastrestore_port) throws IOException {
    this.ni = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");

    this.mcast_port = mcast_port;
    this.mcast_addr = mcast_addr;
    this.controlAddr = InetAddress.getByName(mcast_addr);
    this.ctrladr = new InetSocketAddress(mcast_addr,mcast_port);

    this.mcastbackup_addr = mcastbackup_addr;
    this.mcastbackup_port = mcastbackup_port;
    this.backupAddr = InetAddress.getByName(mcastbackup_addr);
    this.backadr = new InetSocketAddress(mcastbackup_addr, mcastbackup_port);

    this.mcastrestore_addr = mcastrestore_addr;
    this.mcastrestore_port = mcastrestore_port;
    this.restoreAddr = InetAddress.getByName(mcastrestore_addr);
    this.restadr = new InetSocketAddress(mcastrestore_addr, mcastrestore_port);

    this.selector = this.initSelector();

}               //TODO Check all methods/variables used in several thread and check concurrency
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Waiting...\n");
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Process any pending changes
            synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
                Iterator changes = this.pendingChanges.iterator();
                while (changes.hasNext()) {
                    ChangeRequest change = (ChangeRequest) changes.next();
                    switch (change.type) {
                        case ChangeRequest.CHANGEOPS:
                            SelectionKey key = change.socket.keyFor(this.selector);
                            key.interestOps(change.ops);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                this.pendingChanges.clear();
            }

            // Wait for an event in one of the registered channels
            int readyChannels = selector.select();
            if (readyChannels == 0) continue;

            // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
            Iterator selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    System.out.println("Not Valid Key");
                    continue;
                }
                // Check what event is available and deal with it
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    System.out.println("Readable");
                    this.read(key);
                } else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    System.out.println("Writable");
                    this.write(key);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//Channels Initialization - OPTION: REUSEADRR, MULTICAST_LOOPBACK, MULTICAST ON INTERFACE, MULTICAST TIME TO LIVE = 1
public Selector initSelector() throws IOException {
    Selector channelSelector = Selector.open();

    this.controlChannel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, false)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 1)
            .bind(new InetSocketAddress(mcast_port));
    controlChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    MembershipKey key = controlChannel.join(controlAddr, ni);
    controlChannel.register(channelSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

    this.backupChannel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, false)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ni)
            .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 1)
            .bind(new InetSocketAddress(mcastbackup_port));
    backupChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    MembershipKey key1 = backupChannel.join(backupAddr, ni);
    backupChannel.register(channelSelector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);


    return channelSelector;
}

//Read from channel method - Deploys runnable to execute the protocol
public void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    this.readBuffer.clear();

    System.out.println("Listening....");
    String in;

    try {
        InetSocketAddress sa = (InetSocketAddress) channel.receive(this.readBuffer);

        readBuffer.flip();
        ByteBuffer message = readBuffer.slice();

        int i = getReceivingChannel(sa);
        switch(i)
        {
            case BC:
                System.out.println("Backup Service for: " + sa.getHostName());
                initiateBackupService(message);
                break;

            case RC:
                System.out.println("Restore");
                break;

            case CC:
                System.out.println("Control");
                break;
        }

       // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(readBuffer.array()));
        /*String s = new String(readBuffer.array(), 0, readBuffer.limit());
        in = s;*/
       // System.out.println("Received: " + s + " from " + sa.getHostName() + " at port: " + sa.getPort());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        key.cancel();
        channel.close();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    this.selector.wakeup();
}

//Writes to channel pending information when exists
private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    DatagramChannel channel = (DatagramChannel) key.channel();

    synchronized (this.pendingData) {
        List queue = (List) this.pendingData.get(channel);
        // Write until there's not more data ...
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Chunk.CHUNK_SIZE);

            buf.clear().flip();
            buf = (ByteBuffer) queue.get(0);

            int i = channel.send(buf, backadr);
            //System.out.println("Sending to address: " + backadr.getHostName() + " :\n" + new String(buf.array(), 0, buf.array().length) + "\n");
            if (buf.remaining() > 0) {
                // ... or the socket's buffer fills up
                break;
            }
            queue.remove(0);
        }

        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no data");
            // We wrote away all data, so we're no longer interested
            // in writing on this socket. Switch back to waiting for
            // data.

            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        }
    }
}

//Send Method - When the user triggers the backup button this is the class where we add what we want to send to the pendingdata
public void send(DatagramChannel channel, byte[] data) throws IOException {

    synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
        // Indicate we want the interest ops set changed
        this.pendingChanges.add(new ChangeRequest(channel, ChangeRequest.CHANGEOPS, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE));

        // And queue the data we want written
        synchronized (this.pendingData) {
            List queue = (List) this.pendingData.get(channel);
            if (queue == null) {
                queue = new ArrayList();
                this.pendingData.put(channel, queue);
            }
            System.out.println(queue.size());
            queue.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        }
    }

    // Finally, wake up our selecting thread so it can make the required changes
    this.selector.wakeup();
}

public void initiateBackupFileProtocol(File file, int repDegree) throws IOException {
    //TODO Create runnable to execute de backupsubprotocol

    Future future = executor.submit(new BackupSubProtocol(this.executor, this, controlChannel, backupChannel, file, repDegree, backadr));

    try {
        if(future.get() == null){
            System.out.println("Backup Sub-Protocol finished correctly\n");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error while executing BackupSubProtocol.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* FileEntry filee = new FileEntry(file);

    Chunk c = new Chunk(filee, 1, 2,"coisas".getBytes());

    Message back = new PutChunkMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID(), 0, 1, new byte[0]);

    System.out.println(new String(back.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println();

    Message sto = new StoredMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID(), 0);

    System.out.println(new String(sto.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));


    Message get = new GetChunkMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID(), 0);

    System.out.println(new String(get.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));


    Message ch = new ChunkMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID(), 0, new byte[0]);

    System.out.println(new String(ch.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));
    System.out.println();

    Message del = new DeleteMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID());

    System.out.println(new String(del.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));

    Message rem = new RemovedMessage(1, 0, filee.getFileID(), 0);

    System.out.println(new String(rem.constructMessage(), "UTF-8"));
*/

    //send(backupChannel, back.constructMessage());
    //send(controlChannel, str.getBytes());
}

public class ChangeRequest {
    public static final int CHANGEOPS = 2;

    public DatagramChannel socket;
    public int type;
    public int ops;

    public ChangeRequest(DatagramChannel socket, int type, int ops) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.type = type;
        this.ops = ops;
    }
}

public int getReceivingChannel(InetSocketAddress sa)
{
    int port = sa.getPort();

    if(port == mcastbackup_port)
    {
        return BC;
    }
    else if(port == mcast_port)
    {
        return CC;
    }
    else if(port == mcastrestore_port)
    {
        return RC;
    }

    return -1;
}

public void initiateBackupService(ByteBuffer m) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Future future = executor.submit(new BackupService(this.executor, m));

    try {
        if(future.get() == null){
            System.out.println("Backup Sub-Protocol finished correctly\n");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error while executing BackupSubProtocol.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void initiateRestoreFileProtocol(byte[] FileId) throws IOException {
    //TODO Create runnable to execute de backupsubprotocol

    Future future = executor.submit(new RestoreSubProtocol(this.executor, this, controlChannel, restoreChannel, FileId));

    try {
        if(future.get() == null){
            System.out.println("Backup Sub-Protocol finished correctly\n");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Error while executing BackupSubProtocol.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's a print of what I receive:

[image: receive]

It sent supposedly 218 chunks, as I confirmed through Wireshark, but as the image states it skips many of them.

Maybe it is blocking on select, but I can't figure why.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

**Edit #1** - It seems that if I insert a Thread.sleep after sending each datagram it works correctly, is there another aproach?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be aware that UDP isn't reliable: that is to say, it lacks any reliability features, so packet loss is never detected or compensated for. Adding the sleeps lowered the transmission rate and therefore the packet loss rate. You need to implement reliability features of some sort in your protocol.